# fscanf () read error

Tags: c, file-io, scanf

I have a text file which I'm reading in first and last names into a character array of size 20. I'm creating a struct array which holds the "People's" information. 
The text file looks as follows:

```
John Robbins
Teresa Jones
```

my struct is defined as such:

```
struct people {

char name[20];
};
```

Declaration of Persons struct:

```
 struct people *persons[2];
```

After declaring a new struct I read in the names with the following code:

```
for(i=0; i<2; i++)
{  
  fscanf(dp, "%[^\n]s", &persons[i].name[20]);
}
```

However, once I output the names to the console I receive the following:

```
hn Robbins
sa Jones
```

I've done extensive research and cannot find the solution to this problem. Has anyone experienced this problem?

Comment: Show the declaration of the person array please.

Comment: Just added the declaration of the "Persons" struct

Comment: Is it just a typo that you have capitalised Persons in the declaration but not when you use it?

Comment: Yes that's just a typo

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile. persons[i] is not a struct but a pointer to a struct.

Answer (score 5):

```
fscanf(dp, "%[^\n]s", &persons[i].name[20]);
```

This reads the line up to a newline, and then attempts to read an `s` which will fail.  The line up to the newline will be stored after the end of the `name` array in your people struct (which means it will overwrite into the next element of the `persons` array.

You want something like:

```
fscanf(dp, " %19[^\n]%*[^\n]", persons[i].name);
```

instead -- the initial space skips leading whitespace (including any newline from a previous line.)  The `%19[^\n]` reads up to 19 characters or up to a newline and stores it, followed by a terminating NULL (so will use up the entire 20 byte `name` array, but no more).  The `%*[^\n]` will read any additional characters on the line up to (and not including) the newline and throw them away.

You also want to check the return value of the `fscanf` call to make sure it doesn't get an error or end of file:

```
#define MAX_PEOPLE    2
struct people persons[MAX_PEOPLE];

i = 0;
while (i < MAX_PEOPLE && fscanf(dp, " %19[^\n]%*[^\n]", persons[i].name) > 0)
    i++;
```

Comment: It should be `persons[i]->name` according to the posted declaration of `persons`.

Comment: Yeah, he needs to change the declaration to `struct people persons[2];` or the code he had won't even compile.  Making it an array of pointers add the need to allocate space for it as well.